# update hidden field value on the fly

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I am using jquery smartupdater for updating i div with json data. I have to send value of hidden field in request and update the value of same hidden field according to response.

Problem lies in, when i receive response, field value is updated in dom, but updated value does not get appended to url again.

Here is my code:---

```
<div id="device_activities"  class="hl_synopsis">
    <p id="no_update">;No Updates Available </p>;
</div>
<%= hidden_field_tag 'last_act', ''%>
```

and javascript code:--

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    var temp = $('#last_act_id').val();
    console.log("temp-->"+temp);
    $("#device_activities").smartupdater({
        url : '<%= get_activity_path%>',
        data: {"last_act_id":$("#last_act").val()},
        dataType : 'json',
        minTimeout : 6000
    }, function(data) {
            $('#last_act').val(data[data.length-1].id);
            console.log(data[data.length-1].id);
            console.log($('#last_act').val());
        $.each(data, function() {
            $('div#device_activities p#no_update').remove();
            $.each(this, function(key, value) {
                $("div#device_activities").append("<p id='activity'><strong>" + key + " :</strong> " + value + "</p>");
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: please format the code properly

Comment: The id of the div you are reading the value from and the one you are updating are not the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply. I got the issue, it was in smartupdator request format. Smart updator send request configured at the first time repeatedly. In order to send request with updated field value, you've to update smartupdator url.

i got this working by adding:--

$(document).ready(function(){

```
$("#device_activities").smartupdater({
    url : '<%= get_activity_path%>',
    dataType : 'json',
    minTimeout : 10000
}, function(data) {
        <!-- Get last activity id from json and update smartupdater url using it, after that delet id element from json data -->
        $("#device_activities").smartupdater("alterUrl", '<%= get_activity_path%>', {"last_act_id": data[data.length-1].id});   

        $.each(data, function() {
            if(data[0] != undefined && $('div#device_activities p#no_update')){
                $('div#device_activities p#no_update').remove();
            }
            $.each(this, function(key, value) {<!-- update activity div from json -->
                $("div#device_activities").append("<p id='activity'><strong>" + key + " :</strong> " + value + "</p>");
            });
        });
});
```

});